# .jar file not generating in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar

I'm working project which requires another project's .jar file.
I'm using android studio 2.3.3.
Following is code to generate .jar file

```
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
delete 'build/outputs/NAME.jar'}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
into('build/outputs/')
include('classes.jar')
rename ('classes.jar', 'NAME.jar')}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

When i compile a project and call makeJar it executes successful, but I'm unable to find NAME.jar at desired location.
.aar file is generated, but i want .jar file.
Please help me to find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem earlier, I resolved it by clearing invalidated cache and restart studio.

Go to file -> Invalidate caches and restart.
It will take time.

Answer (score 0):

On Android studio 3.1+ the build path got changed. So change the path to "**build/intermediates/packaged-classes/release/**". May it help some one.

```
task makeJar(type: Copy)
{
    from('build/intermediates/packaged-classes/release/')
    into('build/outputs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'NAME.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into your app `build.gradle` file under the dependencies.

`implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`