# Jar is not generated after running build task in android gradle 3.6.1

Tags: android, gradle, build

My build jar task works fine in grade 3.5.3, but it doesn't work in grade 3.6.1. I checked my build files, however, the `/build/intermediates/packaged-classes/` dir is weirdly missing.

The gradle scripts:

```
task buildJar(dependsOn: ['build'], type: Jar) {
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Jar-VersionName': jarVersionName
            attributes 'Jar-VersionCode': jarVersionCode
        }
    }
    from zipTree(file('build/intermediates/packaged-classes/release/classes.jar'))
    appendix = ""
    baseName = "pp"
    version = jarVersionName + "_" + jarVersionCode
    classifier = "release"
    extension = "jar"
    destinationDir = file('build/libs/')
}

//dx --dex --output=target.jar origin.jar
task buildDex(dependsOn: ['buildJar'], type: Exec) {
    workingDir buildDir.absolutePath + "/libs"
    executable "dx"
    args "--dex"
    args "--output=" + buildJar.archiveName
    args buildJar.archiveName
}
```

The error log:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':p2p:buildJar'.
> Cannot expand ZIP '/Users/william/AndroidStudioProjects/Work/lib_plugin/project/build/intermediates/packaged-classes/release/classes.jar' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

I've looked around and apparently I've got the choice between these solutions, but they are so old solution for me.

[No release bundle folder after upgrading Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039532/no-release-bundle-folder-after-upgrading-android-studio/52947381)

[.jar file not generating in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278235/jar-file-not-generating-in-android-studio/52947228)

[Gradle not generate jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54716452/gradle-not-generate-jar)

So, where is the new path of the generated jar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it! When I upgrade gradle version to 4.0, I find the `class.jar` in `build/intermediates/aar_main_jar/release/classes.jar` path.

so, the full build task code is below:

```
def jarPath = buildDir.absolutePath + "/libs"
def jarBaseName = "plugin"

task buildJar(dependsOn: ['build'], type: Jar) {
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Jar-VersionCode': jarVersionCode
        }
    }
    from zipTree(file('build/intermediates/aar_main_jar/release/classes.jar'))
    // [archiveBaseName]-[archiveAppendix]-[archiveVersion]-[archiveClassifier].[archiveExtension]
    archiveBaseName = jarBaseName
    archiveAppendix = null
    archiveVersion = "$jarVersionName-$jarVersionCode"
    archiveClassifier = "release"
    archiveExtension = "jar"
    destinationDirectory = file(jarPath)
}

// dx --dex --output=target.jar origin.jar
task buildDex(dependsOn: ['buildJar'], type: Exec) {
    workingDir jarPath
    executable "dx"
    args "--dex"
    args "--output=" + buildJar.archiveFileName.get()
    args buildJar.archiveFileName.get()
}
```

Comment: For God's sake. Why they keep changing minor stupid things breaking everything. This environment is ridiculous.

Comment: Work for me Thk you!