# I can't fin the .jar file in my android studio project

Tags: java, plugins, jar, nativescript

I try to create a custom plugin to take pictures on nativescript. But when I want export the jar to create that plugin, I don't find it. I searched it in the build files (bundles and packaged-class) without find anything.

Following my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}

// task to delete the old jar
task deleteOldJar(type: Delete) {
    delete'release/ToastPlugin.jar'
}

// task to export contents as jar
task exportJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release')
    include('classes.jar')
    // name the plugin
    rename('classes.jar','ToastPlugin.jar')
}

exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar, build)
```

The exportJar works fine but the release package is not created and the ToastPlugin.jar is not present.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: To precise my method, I followed this tutorial: https://nativescript.org/blog/plugins-and-jars/ .

Comment: To explicit what happens, exportJar finishes without any error but the folder release doesn't appear. I also can't find the jar file in the build repertory.

Answer (score 0):

After generating your jar you can find it in your realese folder.

Follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/widle-studio/how-to-export-jar-file-from-android-studio-project-8af3a8d1bfcd) for details.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it didn't work. I can't find the concerned file in the bundles package or another so I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the file. It was in /build/intermediates/aar_main_jar/release/ directory and not in bundles like it was written in the different tutorials I've found. Unfortunately, I found this topic just after I have solve the problem: [Jar is not generated after running build task in android gradle 3.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650584/jar-is-not-generated-after-running-build-task-in-android-gradle-3-6-1) .
I hope it will help people in the same case.